# Получение данных в UI поток.

Tags: многопоточность, android, java

Добрый вечер.
Есть activity в котором создается экземпляр Handler для обработки сообщения из другого потока. Внутри handleMessage() я могу менять поля которые являются элементами UI(TextView, EditText и т.д.) , но с полями других типов ничего не происходит. Как можно получить newhtml в поле activity?

```
public class AboutUsActivity extends Activity {

Handler h;

TextView largeText;

List<String> stringLinks;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    stringLinks = new ArrayList<String>();

    largeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    h = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {

            HtmlParser parser;

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            try {

                parser = new HtmlParser(String.valueOf(msg.getData()));

                List<TagNode> links = parser.getContentByClassName("ab");

                for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = stringLinks.iterator(); iterator

                .hasNext();) {

                    TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();

                    result.append(divElement.getText().toString());

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            largeText.setText(newhtml); // Работает, отображается текст

            stringLinks.add(newhtml); // Компилируется без ошибок, но в
                                        // список ничего не добавляется

        }

    };

    MyHttpClientUsage connect = new MyHttpClientUsage(h);

    try {

        connect.getInfoAbout();

    } catch (HttpException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: если так сложно, пользуйся AsyncTask лучше

Answer (score 2):

Действительно, воспользуйтесь AsyncTask-ом. В нем вы выделите код, который должен работать в UI-потоке и в параллельном потоке. В методе асинкТаска

```
onPostExecute()
```

вы прорефрешите UI и все будет в порядке

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что UI поток должен "дышать", то есть вы ему должны вернуть управление, чтобы он смог отобразить изменения которые вы внесли в элементы UI. Если вы полагаете, что как только изменили содержимое `TextView` то оно немедленно отобразится - то вынужден вас расстроить: ваша картина мира неверна.

Мессидж простой: пока вы не вернете управление UI потоку изменения в UI не произойдут.